# The concept of "taking turn" in Fairclough's (1995) Critical Discourse Analysis

Tags: discourse-analysis, discourse

I am currently reading Fairclough's (1995) Critical Discourse Analysis (CDA) as a supplement to my research, that is, corpus-based CDA on nominal collocations in Russian news corpus.

I am trying to disambiguate several conceptual ideas Fairclough mentioned in his book, one being "taking turn" in CDA. He argues that this "taking turn" can influence the "natural ideology" of discourse, i.e., what interlocutors came to think as what is the common sense in the discourse.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: Please provide a definition of taking turns (with an s), an obvious necessity here. Turn taking **refers to dialogue**. Taking one's turn to speak. It's a higher level organizational property of speech. According to him: https://newlearningonline.com/literacies/chapter-8/fairclough-on-discourse

Comment: Norman Fairclough suggests that dominant ideologies become "naturalized" in society; that is, a system of values and subject positions comes to be accepted as natural, obvious, or correct, or as Fairclough puts it, as "common sense". [and] *Such assumptions and expectations are implicit, backgrounded, taken for granted, not things that people are consciously aware of, rarely explicitly formulated or examined or questioned.* (77) muse.jhu.edu/article/31709 Obviously, this concerns spoken language rather than written text.